# Protractor. Applying locator for Error text presence, test is being passing despite wrong text

Tags: javascript, text, protractor

Trying to apply **cssContainingText** assertion
(When input incorrect text in the text field, under field appearing text error, I need to make sure this error text has arisen.

I decided to use **cssContainingText** locator like an assertion

```
await expect(await browser.element(by.cssContainingText('.common-form-error', 'We do not recognize that email address or password.Please try again or Sign-up to create an account.')))
            .toAppear(2000, 'Error message did not appear');
```

But the problem is no matter what the text I put there, the test is passing anyway, despite wrong text in code line.

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have an improper usage of promises, using the `await`.
The `toAppear` should be called to a simple `ElementFinder` of protractor. 
So no need of the `await` inside the brackets.

Try to remove all your `await` cause they can be avoided, also the first one, returning the promise inside the spec block, and let protractor to resolve and wait for it. So you could try something like this:

```
return expect(
    browser.element(
        by.cssContainingText('.common-form-error', 'We do not recognize that email address or password.Please try again or Sign-up to create an account.')
    )
)
.toAppear(2000, 'Error message did not appear');
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks.
Changed to your recommendation (with wrong text inside) 
But test still passing

Comment: it('Sign in with correct email email and incorrect password', async
    function () {
    loginEmailField.sendKeys('tylermac2030@gmail.com');
    await loginPassField.sendKeys('Alexandro123');
    await signInButton.click();
    await browser.sleep(1500);
    return expect(browser.element(by.cssContainingText            
      ('.common-form-error',
    'Please try again or Sign-up to create an account.')))
     .toAppear(2000, 'Error message did not appear');

Comment: @AlexanderTunick the `toAppear` is part of a plugin which introduces new jasmine selectors. Are you sure you are importing that one fine?

Comment: In global beforeEach in protractor.conf I have import jasmine.addMatchers(matchers) which is highlighted correctly and seen by protractor

Comment: maybe because of this locator is not supported by matchers https://github.com/Xotabu4/jasmine-protractor-matchers

Comment: Are you sure you are using jasmine inside protractor and not overriding it with chai for example?

Comment: yeah, pretty sure. As for chai, I even didn't install it. thanks for the help, I wrote on a thematical forum to find out what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

1. You can remove 'await' outside the brackets, but not the inside:

`expect(await browser...)`

2. Why don't you use ExpectedConditions?

`let myError = await element(by.cssContainingText('.common-form-error', 'We do not recognize that email address or password.Please try again or Sign-up to create an account.'))`

`await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(myError), 2000, "Error message did not appear");`

Answer (score 0):

this works perfectly:

```
    await expect(await targeting_page.list_type_title.getText()).toBe(targeting_page.type_1,'fail
 output');
```